# How to disable auto alignment?

Tags: android, eclipse, alignment

I'm building an android project and I'm using eclipse.
I just can't figure out how to disable the annoying auto alignment.
I just want to place buttons wherever I want to drop them on the GUI interface but it just keeps
to align them one to another. I've tried to delete those alignment lines in the xml code
but it still brings them back as I move the buttons on the GUI interface.

Is there an way to disable that function?

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an way to disable that function?

Not in a way that you will find satisfactory, I suspect.

You have not really explained what the "alignment lines" are, so we are forced to guess. My guess is that the "alignment lines" are because you are working with a `RelativeLayout` container. Quoting [the JavaDocs for `RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), `RelativeLayout` is:

> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent.

And, quoting [the guide for `RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html):

> RelativeLayout is a view group that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent RelativeLayout area (such as aligned to the bottom, left of center).

Hence, the "alignment lines" are there, and are replaced by the GUI builder, because they are the point behind using a `RelativeLayout` container.

Of course, you are welcome to change the container that you are working with to something else.

However, in general, Android does not really support very well your stated objective ("I just want to place buttons wherever I want to drop them on the GUI interface"). Just as you don't do that in Web development, you don't do that in Android development, and for much the same reason: you need to take different sizes into account (browser window size for Web, screen size for Android). `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `TableLayout`, and `GridLayout` are all designed to have you specify widgets plus rules for positioning and sizing, so that you can design a UI that will accommodate the difference between a 3" and a 4.5" screen, for example. This is akin to using HTML tags and CSS rules to define content and its positioning in a Web page. Eclipse's drag-and-drop GUI builder for Android can assist in your definitions of these rules, as you are perhaps seeing with your "alignment lines" for `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I'm really new to android development, usually I develop for iOS where it's very easy just to drag and drop anything wherever you want. I was hoping it is possible to the same for android. I'm already using RelativeLayout but I just can't get it right, whenever I'm setting a position of one button it is relative to some other buttons and then when I try to place them it moves the first one and I just can't solve it. If you know any tutorial which explains how to do this properly it could help me very much.

Comment: @AlexFish: "usually I develop for iOS where it's very easy just to drag and drop anything wherever you want" -- I'm no iOS developer, but I'd be stunned and disappointed if the Apple HIG lets you "drag and drop anything wherever you want", even if the tools support it. "If you know any tutorial which explains how to do this properly it could help me very much" -- you need to learn how the containers (e.g., `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`) work and how to design your GUI using those containers. Drag-and-drop is a means to an end, not an end in itself.

Comment: @AlexFish: In terms of where to learn how to use the containers and such, the online documentation, starting at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/overview.html, is unfortunately weak, but it does exist. Beyond that, books, blogs, StackOverflow, etc. are your primary resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be able to help. If you set your layout to Relative Layout you can drag and drop any of the views wherever on the eclipse GUI.